# What should be the approach for implementing data storing

Tags: c#

I would be having variables

> Page No
>
> Position
>
> URL
>
> Text
>
> Word

I would be having above for different words i.e for word 1 I may have

> Page No =1
>
> Position =10
>
> URL abc.com
>
> Text realtext
>
> Word real

and so on so I have to save them in list.

First I thought of declaring list for each then I thought it is not a good idea.

Is there any way to save them so that I can access data according to any url?

I do not have to use database. These lists are temporary and will be populated each time program starts.

Comment: Shot in the dark, I'd probably use a database.  I'm not sure what you're asking though, so you may want to clarify a bit (do you want to persist them, or store them in a data structure (dictionary?), etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a class with the variables you want as properties:

```
class Storage
{

    public string Url
    {

       get;
       set;

    }

    //etc.

}
```

Edit: you can use this class to store your information:

```
Storage myStorage = new Storage();
myStorage.Url = "www.example.com";
//etc
```

Then you can store each object you created in a generic Dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, Storage> dict = new Dictionary<string, Storage>();
dict.Add(myStorage.Url, myStorage);
```

Edit: And you can retrieve each object with the url:

```
Storage fromDict = dict["www.example.com"];
```

Comment: I think i need some more detail .Thanks